# How to change the VBA code of a Word macro to create a hyperlink to a document with a .docx or .doc extension?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

How to change the VBA code below so that the Microsoft Word Macro works for documents with the extension .docx, too?

ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
NJuiz & "/" & NumVt & "**.doc**", SubAddress:=""

Comment: A hyperlink is always a link to a specific file, not a range of documents. So a wildcard approach makes no sense in this context. You'll have to test the file ending of the target file, then construct a hyperlink with either .doc or .docx.

Comment: Does the linked already file exist when you create the link in the Word document?

Comment: You could code to first check for the existence of the file and write the extension to match the existing file's extension.